# Error installing Virtualenv for Python programming Bitcoin

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, virtualenv, bitcoin

I am trying to set the tools for Jupyter notebook, needed for going through the book called: Programming Bitcoin by Jimmy Song
I've done all the steps from the guide: https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/programming-bitcoin/9781492031482/preface01.html#setting_up

but got stuck on the step 7:
While typing the command: `virtualenv -p`
I get this error:

`usage: virtualenv [--version] [--with-traceback] [-v | -q] [--read-only-app-data ] [--app-data APP_DATA] [--reset-app-data] [--upgrade-embed-wheels] [--discovery {builtin}] [-p py] [--try-first-with py_exe] virtualenv: error: argument -p/--python: expected one argument SystemExit: 2`

The screenshot:
[Link to the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QoDP8.jpg)

Could there be a fix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error says, your command is missing an argument.

> ```
> error: argument -p/--python: expected one argument
> ```

Enter the full command as given in the instructions you linked to:

```
virtualenv -p C:\PathToYourPythonInstallation\Python.exe .venv
```

Replace the path with your actual path.